# Pandas sum column data based on summation points

Tags: python, pandas

Based on a given dataframe e.g

```
         x    y
0        1    2
1        2    4
2        3    6
3        4    8
4        5    10
5        6    12
6        7    14
```

I would like to calculate the sum of the in between values based on given summation points e.g

```
         x 
0        1
1        3
2        6
3        7
```

So that the final result will look like below

```
         x    y
0        1    2
1        3    10    #sum of y values for x between (2-3)
2        6    30    #sum of y values for x between (4-6)
3        7    14
```

can you please help me with an example/idear on how should i approach this?
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, create a custom group and [`groupby`+`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html).

Note that I used a simple list for the x points, if you have a dataframe `df_ref`, use `x = df_ref['x'].to_list()`

```
x = [1,3,6,7]

df2 = (df.groupby(df['x'].isin(x).shift(fill_value=0).cumsum(), as_index=False)
         .agg({'x':'last', 'y': 'sum'})
      )
```

output:

```
    x   y
0   1   2
1   3  10
2   6  30
3   7  14
```

custom group:

```
>>> df['x'].isin(x).shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    3
```